# Mongodb on Mavericks

Tags: mongodb, installation, osx-mavericks

I just updated to Mavericks and trying to get all my required tools and software in place.
My mongodb is not working after installing mongodb through brew.

I did: `brew install mongodb --devel`

Then, I ran mongod& on terminal. This gives me:

```
ERROR: dbpath (/data/db) does not exist.
Create this directory or give existing directory in --dbpath.
```

I tried creating a directory: `mkdir -p /data/db` and I got permission denied as the error.

I am referring to this website "`http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/`" and installing Mongo using Homebrew.

Has anyone faced this issue before? Where do I actually find `/data/db` directory to give permissions to it? I tried `ls -la` in my home folder, but couldn't find this directory.

Please ignore. Here is what helped me to solve the problem:

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /data/db/
$ sudo chown `id -u` /data/db
```

Comment: Please ignore this question, I tried something which worked. Here is what helped me:$ sudo mkdir -p /data/db/
$ sudo chown `id -u` /data/db

Comment: you have a delete button below your question if you wish to remove it.